# How to handle the issue Upload JSON as empty in iphone

Tags: iphone, json, ios5

I have a JSON string to upload the server is worked perfectly. My thought is when Upload JSON have no data that time also got the message successfully uploaded.

My JSON with values Look like this format:

```
{
 "Data" : [
      [view] [17/09/2012] [msg];
]
}
```

My JSON without values look like this format:

```
{
"Data" : [

]
 }
```

how to handle these issue and identify the JSON with data or empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the json, then check the collections using standard empty tests ...

```
// note this function assumes json as you specified: dictionary containing array
// for the key @"Data"
//
- (BOOL)jsonIsEmpty:(NSString *)jsonString {

    NSError *e = nil;
    NSData* data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

    NSArray *dataArray = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Data"];
    return dataArray.count == 0;
}
```

Comment: i have another one question can i ask

Comment: Sure.  That's what SO is for :-).  Ask here or even better, start a new one.